# Find the double integral limit.

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, contest-math

I want to solve this problem by using $\varepsilon-\delta $ definition of a limit, but failed. How to compute this limit?

$f\in C\left( \left[ 0,1 \right] \times \left[ 0,1 \right] \right) $

$$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } {\left( {\frac{{\left( {2n + 1} \right)!}}{{{{\left( {n!} \right)}^2}}}} \right)^2}\int_0^1 {\int_0^1 {{{\left[ {xy\left( {1 - x} \right)\left( {1 - y} \right)} \right]}^n}f\left( {x,y} \right)} } {\text{d}}x{\text{d}}y$$

This problem appears in the "15th Annual Vojtěch Jarník International Mathematical Competition"
on 6th April 2005 as the third problem from Category ll. A solution is provided in the following [pdf](https://vjimc.osu.cz/storage/uploads/j15solutions.pdf). Are there also alternatives ways to find the limit?

Comment: Really? With $\;\epsilon-\delta\;$ ?? To begin with, you need first to evaluate, or be told, what the limit is...if it exists, of course.

Comment: I think  it's  zero,then  I  want  to prove  it.

Comment: It looks really horrible and messy...and we don't even know what that function $\;f\;$ there is.

Comment: Sorry,something is  omitted.

Comment: I think you'll have more luck if you try to prove that the limit is $f(1/2,1/2)$. (The function $x(1-x)$ has its maximum at $x=1/2$, and when you raise it to the $n$th power, it will become more narrowly centered around that point as $n$ grows.)

Comment: @HansLundmark I  think  we can  replace f with  its maximum value M and its minimun value m,and then we  can  try Squeeze Theorem.

Comment: It looks like an example of Laplace's method. You need to do a Taylor expansion of $f(x, y)$ near $(1/2, 1/2)$ where $x(1-x) y  (1-y)$ has its maximum.

Comment: See also: [Find $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{(2n+1)!}{(n!)^2}\right)^2\int_0^1 \int_0^1 (xy(1-x)(1-y))^n f(x,y)dxdy$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4549597)

Answer (score 4):

@HansLundmark has already given away the answer. To prove it we divide the region $R=\{(x,y)|0\le x\le1,0\le y\le1\}$ into $R_1=\left\{(x,y)|\frac12-r<x<\frac12+r,\frac12-r<y<\frac12+r\right\}$ and $R_2=R\setminus R_1$. Then
$$\begin{align}I=\int\int_R\left[xy(1-x)(1-y)\right]^nf(x,y)d^2A&=\int\int_R\left[xy(1-x)(1-y)\right]^nf\left(\frac12,\frac12\right)d^2A\\
&\quad+\int\int_{R_1}\left[xy(1-x)(1-y)\right]^n\left[f(x,y)-f\left(\frac12,\frac12\right)\right]d^2A\\
&\quad+\int\int_{R_2}\left[xy(1-x)(1-y)\right]^n\left[f(x,y)-f\left(\frac12,\frac12\right)\right]d^2A\\
&=I_0+I_1+I_2\end{align}$$
Now,
$$I_0=f\left(\frac12,\frac12\right)\left[B(n+1,n+1)\right]^2=\left[\frac{\left(n!\right)^2}{(2n+1)!}\right]^2f\left(\frac12,\frac12\right)$$
Since $f(x,y)$ is continuous at $(x,y)=\left(1/2,1/2\right)$ we know that for any $\epsilon_1>0$ there is a $\delta_1(\epsilon_1)>0$ such that $\left|f(x,y)-f\left(\frac12,\frac12\right)\right|<\epsilon_1$ whenever
$$\sqrt{\left(x-\frac12\right)^2+\left(y-\frac12\right)^2}<\delta_1$$
So we choose
$$0<r<\min\left(\frac{\delta_1\left(\frac{\epsilon}2\right)}{\sqrt2},\frac12\right)$$
So that
$$\begin{align}\left|I_1\right|&\le\int\int_{R_1}\left[xy(1-x)(1-y)\right]^n\left|f(x,y)-f\left(\frac12,\frac12\right)\right|d^2A\\
&<\int\int_{R_1}\left[xy(1-x)(1-y)\right]^n\left(\frac{\epsilon}2\right)d^2A\\
&<\int\int_{R}\left[xy(1-x)(1-y)\right]^n\left(\frac{\epsilon}2\right)d^2A\\
&=\left[\frac{\left(n!\right)^2}{(2n+1)!}\right]^2\left(\frac{\epsilon}2\right)\end{align}$$
If $n\ge2$ then $\frac83n=2n+\frac23n>2n+1$ so
$$\begin{align}\frac{(2n+1)!}{n\cdot2^{2n}\left(n!\right)^2}&=\frac{(2n+1)}n\prod_{k=1}^n\frac{(2k-1)(2k)}{(2k)(2k)}=\frac{(2n+1)}n\left(\frac12\right)\left(\frac34\right)\prod_{k=3}^n\frac{(2k-1)}{(2k)}\\
&=\frac{(2n+1)}{\frac83n}\prod_{k=3}^n\frac{(2k-1)}{(2k)}\le1\end{align}$$
Also the continuity of $f$ over a closed set $R$ implies that it is bounded on that set so there is some $M$ such that $\left|f(x,y)\right|\le M$ for all $(x,y)\in R$, so by the triangle inequality
$$\left|f(x,y)-f\left(\frac12,\frac12\right)\right|\le2M$$
For $(x,y)\in R\supset R_2$. Also $xy(1-x)(1-y)$ attains its maximum absolute value in $R_2$ at $\left(\frac12\pm r,\frac12\right)$ and at $\left(\frac12,\frac12\pm r\right)$ of $\frac1{16}\left(1-4r^2\right)$. Then
$$\begin{align}\left|I_2\right|&\le\int\int_{R_2}\left[xy(1-x)(1-y)\right]^n\left|f(x,y)-f\left(\frac12,\frac12\right)\right|d^2A\\
&\le\int\int_{R_2}\frac1{2^{4n}}\left(1-4r^2\right)^n(2M)d^2A\\
&=\int\int_{R_2}\left[\frac{(2n+1)!}{n\cdot2^{2n}\left(n!\right)^2}\right]^2\left[\frac{n\cdot\left(n!\right)^2}{(2n+1)!}\right]^2\left(1-4r^2\right)^n(2M)d^2A\\
&\le\left[\frac{\left(n!\right)^2}{(2n+1)!}\right]^2n^2\left(1-4r^2\right)^n(2M)\int\int_{R_2}d^2A\\
&\le\left[\frac{\left(n!\right)^2}{(2n+1)!}\right]^2n^2\left(1-4r^2\right)^n(2M)\int\int_{R}d^2A\\
&=\left[\frac{\left(n!\right)^2}{(2n+1)!}\right]^2(2M)n^2\left(1-4r^2\right)^n\end{align}$$
We may establish via L'Hopital's Rule that for $0<r<\frac12$
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}g(n,r)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}n^2\left(1-4r^2\right)^n=0$$
Which means that for any $\epsilon_2>0$ there is an $N_2\left(\epsilon_2,r\right)$ such that $g(n,r)<\epsilon_2$ whenever $n>N_2\left(\epsilon_2,r\right)$ so we choose
$$n>\max\left(N_2\left(\frac{\epsilon}{4M},r\right),2\right)$$
Which yields the desired
$$\left|I_2\right|\le\left[\frac{\left(n!\right)^2}{(2n+1)!}\right]^2\left(\frac{\epsilon}2\right)$$
Given such an $n$ we can now put together
$$\begin{align}\left|\left[\frac{(2n+1)!}{\left(n!\right)^2}\right]^2I-f\left(\frac12,\frac12\right)\right|&=\left|\left[\frac{(2n+1)!}{\left(n!\right)^2}\right]^2\left(I_0+I_1+I_2\right)-f\left(\frac12,\frac12\right)\right|\\
&\le\left|\left[\frac{(2n+1)!}{\left(n!\right)^2}\right]^2\left(\left|I_1\right|+\left|I_2\right|\right)\right|\\
&<\left|\frac{\epsilon}2+\frac{\epsilon}2\right|=\epsilon\end{align}$$
Let's see... we divided by $4M$ earlier, but if $4M=0$ then the limit is trivially $f\left(1/2,1/2\right)=0$. So this limit gives us another realization of the Dirac $\delta$ function.

Comment: It would be nice if downvoters would explain what they found lacking in my answer.